# What to do with excess internet bandwitch?

Tags: internet, internet-connection, bandwidth

I have pretty decent internet speed but I would like to know what to do with excess bandwidth. As I am already a part of BOINC Distributed computing I would prefer something charitable.

I searched up Google but couldn't find anything substantial apart from streaming Media. Tor seems good but the potential risks involved make me vary of the whole things. I tried seeding Ubuntu Torrents but they seemed covered.

Comment: Is this a residential connection?

Comment: Letting other people with the same ISP have a less congested connection isn't enough?

Comment: Yes it is a Residential Line.                                                                                                            "Letting other people with the same ISP have a less congested connection isn't enough?"                                                                                           Well the ISP is a local guy so not much traffic here. You buy a 4 MBPS plan you actually get 4.5MBPS. If the ISP minded additional traffic he wouldn't be providing eight times the promised speed while torrenting.